# Why am I getting an integer precision error when I run: heroku run python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, model

I have deployed a Django app on Heroku, but I want to migrate to PostgreSQL, so I am following a video tutorial on YouTube on how to do that. In the tutorial, we have to run `Heroku run python manage.py migrate` to migrate my current SQLite database to the PostgreSQL one on Heroku. I keep getting this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type date to double precision
LINE 1: ...cted" TYPE double precision USING "lastInteracted"::double p...
```

Here is my models.py file. I am pretty sure that the problem is in the `Conversation` model with the `lastInteracted` variable, but I do not know why it is happening.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import CharField
from django.db.models.fields.files import FileField, ImageField, ImageFieldFile
from django.utils.timezone import localtime, now
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
import sys
from django.core.files.base import File
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile


class User(AbstractUser):
    userType = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="student")
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(
        null=True, blank=True, default="blankUserIcon.svg")


class Classroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Classroom")
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="teacher")
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="cardBlue")


class Comment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    text = CharField(max_length=5000, default="")
    commenter = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="commenter", null=True)


class Announcement(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(
        Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="classroom", null=True)
    body = CharField(max_length=20000, default="")
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creator", null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment, blank=True)


class Text(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sender")
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reciever")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    text = CharField(max_length=1000, default="")


class Conversation(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user1")
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user2")
    texts = models.ManyToManyField(Text, blank=True)
    lastInteracted = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    readUser1 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    readUser2 = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class FileModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=True)

    def name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)


class Submission(models.Model):
    resubmitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    grade = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(FileModel, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, related_name="submitter", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())


class Assignment(models.Model):
    givenFiles = models.ManyToManyField(FileModel, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20000, default="")
    duedate = models.DateTimeField()
    submissions = models.ManyToManyField(Submission, blank=True)
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(
        Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="belongingToClassroom", null=True)


class MCanswer(models.Model):
    answer = models.IntegerField(default=-1)


class MultipleChoiceQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    correctOption = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    selectedOption = models.IntegerField(default=-1)


class QuizSubmission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    grade = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(MCanswer, blank=True)


class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="Untitled Quiz")
    submissions = models.ManyToManyField(QuizSubmission, blank=True)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(MultipleChoiceQuestion, blank=True)
    duedate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(
        Classroom, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

To clarify, the `lastInteracted` variable holds the current time since epoch time in seconds. I verified this and it is indeed less than 2.47B which is the integer max value.

And here are the code snippets of the times where I try to use this lastInteracted variable:

```
conversation = Conversation()
conversation.lastInteracted = int(time.time())
```

and

```
convs = (Conversation.objects.filter(
            Q(user1=request.user) | Q(user2=request.user))).order_by('-lastInteracted')
```

Comment: "we have to run `Heroku run python manage.py migrate` to migrate my current SQLite database to the PostgreSQL one on Heroku"—capitals matter. You'd run `heroku run`, not `Heroku run`. But more importantly, that's _not_ what this command does. It applies database migrations to change your database schema from one version to another. It has _nothing at all_ to do with changing database management systems.

Comment: The problem, probably, is that you have database migrations that don't work on Postgres. Database servers aren't drop-in replacements for each other. Your generated database migrations are likely the problem, not your models.

Comment: @Chris yeah, I am running the lowercase version for sure. I am also following the exact steps in this tutorial and it worked fine for him: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFFtDLZnbSs&t=19s . Do you have a suggestion if you are good with django? I am really confused.

Comment: You are not getting an `integer` precision problem you are getting `double precision(float)` one.  Also if you declared the field as `date` in the SQLite database it would just be ignored as SQLite does not have a `date` type.

Comment: We're not going to watch a video simply to understand your question. Please read [ask].

Comment: Yeah okay.. I fixed the issue with a database reset. I made all the migrations again and it worked. Thanks for the time guys.

Answer (score 0):

I reset the database by deleting it and deleting the migrations folder as well. I also removed the default=datetime.now() from all of the models and these changes seemed to have worked. Not sure if this will help anyone, but putting an answer here anyways.